# how to save my dropdown selected values to a textbox...using javascript?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, dropdown, viewbag

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult ItemInsert()
        {
            ViewBag.Category = new SelectList(db.CategoryMasters.ToList(), "CategoryId", "CategoryName");
            ItemViewModel item = new ItemViewModel();
            return PartialView(item);
        }
```

**View**

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoryId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownList("Category", ViewBag.Category as SelectList, new { @id = "catagory" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

how to save dropdown values using javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**View**

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoryId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
               <div hidden>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.CategoryId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "categoryid" } })</div>
                    @Html.DropDownList("any value", ViewBag.category as SelectList,"--SELECT--", new { @id = "category" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#category").change(function () {
            var value = $(this).val();
            alert(+value)
            $("#categoryid").val(value);
        });
    });
</script>
```